# Adding the Print Document Option To The Right-Click Contextual Menu?

Tags: macos, automator, printing, documentation

In Windows it is possible to print a document on the desktop by right-clicking on it and choosing **Print Document** in the contextual menu that appears. By default this option is  unfortunately not given in OS X.

Is it therefore possible to create this option and therefore aid the printing of documents on a Mac ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested on [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508/http://macthoughts.net/20130107-173), you can use the following applescript :

```
tell application "Your Printer Name Here"
   activate
   print theFile without print dialog
   quit
end tell
```

To add it to the contextual menu, do as usual : Create a new automator service with this script.

Don't forget to select **Service receives selected file and folders** in the app you want (At least Finder but it can be from any app).

Comment: This will come in very useful :)

Answer (score -3):

If you're wondering how to create a new automator service check out http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/customize-mac-right-click-menu/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.